# Is there a way to perform this inner join in sql?

Tags: sql

I have a sql database with two tables. 
The first table is named Workers with columns: id, name and includes values:

```
1, Mark
2, David
3, Peter
```

The second is named WorkingHours with: id, hours, date and includes values:

```
1, 5, '2019-07-20'
1, 4, '2019-07-21'
3, 6, '2019-07-10'
3, 4, '2019-07-20'
```

I want to make a query that will show a view for '2019-07-20' like this:

```
id     name       hours
1      Mark       5
2      David  
3      Peter      4
```

If my query is:

```
SELECT W.*, H.hours
  FROM Workers W
    INNER JOIN WorkingHours H ON W.id = H.id
  WHERE H.date = '2019-07-20'
```

I will not get David. How can I get him too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `left join` and `coalesce()` to get 0 hours for the workers that do not have hours on '2019-07-20'

```
SELECT W.*, coalesce(H.hours, 0) hours 
FROM Workers W 
    LEFT JOIN WorkingHours H ON W.id = H.id AND H.date = '2019-07-20'
```

If you don't want 0's, use `H.hours` instead of `coalesce(H.hours, 0)` which will return `null`.

Comment: That's the solution! Thank you very much!!

Comment: May I ask one more question? In this query is there a way to add a column showing working days count for the month (2019-07-01 to 2019-07-31) for every worker? In other words we need to show the number of rows for every worker in that column.

Comment: This query is about a specific day. It would not make sense to add a column like the counter of days. You need a query that will use group by and aggregation.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with another query? We need this extra column to be able to watch working activity.

Comment: Post a question with all sample data and explain what you need. But as I mentioned before this will be something different, not a new column in the query in my code, because it would not make sense to mix one day's data with say a month's data.

Comment: Finally, no need to ask. I made it myself with left join two SELECT statements.